# Send Parameters from a Marketing Automation Platform using API

Tags: google-apps-script

1- I've created a script on **Google Apps Script** to send email via **Gmail** with an **API** address. I checked it with the **Postman**, and it was successful:

```
function sendMail() {
  GmailApp.sendEmail('xxx@gmail.com','title','Test the body')
}

function doGet(){
  sendMail();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Email Sent!')
}
```

2- I'm using a **Marketing Automation** platform, allowing me to build my own journey with different **API modules**. What I want to do is that I put an  API module there to use the first script of this question (No.1), in order to send my new users an email via Gmail:
[image]

As you may see in this image, I use **POST** method, with the deployed address of my API on **Google Apps Script**, and *these codes* in the body of my API module:

```
{
    "title": "Welcome Dear {{user["system"]["firstName"]}}",
    "email": {{user["system"]["email"]}},
    "body": "We are happy to see you on board! :)"
}
```

But the problem is that I'm not receive any parameters on my email when I run this module.

Comment: You may want to check the spelling of `ContentService`.

Comment: @doubleunary the text is mistakenly written here, I did the right one on my Apps Script. I'm gonna edit it now

Answer (score 1):

Use a `doPost(e)` function that uses the `e` event parameter. Examine the object you receive to get the `title`, `email` and `body`.

See [request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters).

Comment: don't you think I have to use `doPost` function, as the marketing automation platform sends me an error, that states that I'm not using a `doPost` function on my script

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't matter which one I choose? Since I have to send a few parameters like email and title, I was thinking that I have to use `POST`. Am I right?

Comment: I've written a code like this:
`function doPost(e){
  sendMail(e);
  e.email = {"email": email}
  e.title = {"title": title}
  e.body = {"body": body}
  return ContentSetvice.createTextOutput('Email Sent!')
}

function sendMail() {
  GmailApp.sendEmail({"Email.$": "$.input.email"},{"Title.$": "$.input.title"},{"Body.$": "$.input.body"})
}`

Comment: Actually, the question is still the same. What has been changed?

Comment: Thanks. And according to your help, may I know what's wrong with my code above in the comment?

Comment: The code you quote is semantically incorrect. The `sendMail()` function lacks a parameter and does not have the code to to deal with the `e` object. The assignments you show seem to be the wrong way around. See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).